Did I break my PCV system housing?
2012 Volvo C30 T5 – While trying to diagnose an unrelated issue (“Engine System Service Required” message), I was trying to open the PCV diaphragm cover to check the state of the PCV diaphragm.
I pushed a little too hard with the screwdriver, and heard a “crack”.  It seems that I cracked part of the plastic PCV housing, which now wiggles a little bit (it didn’t before).
I turned on the engine - no codes, it’s not pissing oil everywhere, and I don’t hear the telltale “squealing” PCV noise.
I did however notice that the idle sounded rough.  Also, there was a smell of oil (I think).
How can I tell if I broke my PCV system?  Is it safe to drive around until I properly diagnose it?  Is there any risk driving with a damaged PCV system could lead to catastrophic engine failure?
Below is a photo of a replacement PCV.  The plastic part circled in red is what I broke.


You can only be absolutely certain you broke it by reading the car's computer with sophisticated equipment when it's beyond threshold level.  You can be reasonably certain, however, just by the rough idle and smell of oil.  Have it replaced, even if you don't hear a squealing sound.
Sure, it's safe to drive with a broken one.  Many people drive with a broken one for tens of thousands of miles without a catastrophe.  If you have no CEL light on the dashboard, it's likely only partially broken.  If you are worried about the very remote possibility of crankcase pressure becoming so high that it damages piston rings, leave the dipstick pulled out a little bit.

I did notice a surging idle (randomly going up to 900 rpm and then back down to 750 every 30 seconds), as well as a CEL code P0507 (Idle RPM Higher than Expected).  I also thought I smelled some oil.  It’s not looking good for my PCV…
